# Generate a normal map with a color map in Three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I started learning Three js and I was looking for a way to convert a color map into a normal map. What I want to do is to try and make the normal map based on this color map [[image 1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyHMP.jpg), by changing the pixels based on their color so it looks like this normal map [[image 2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfIXe.jpg). I don't want to simply upload the files since I'm trying to minimize the weight of the project as much as possible. Here is what I already tried :

```
let img = new Image();

img.src = './texture/color.jpg';
img.onload = function () {
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    document.getElementById('body').appendChild(canvas)
    const c = canvas.getContext('2d')
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    c.fillStyle = '#EEEEEE';
    c.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

    //draw background image
    c.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    //draw a box over the top
    c.fillStyle = "rgba(200, 0, 0, 0)";
    c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    draw(c, canvas);
};


function draw(c, canvas)
{


    let img2 = c.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width,canvas.height);
    console.log(img2.data)
    let d = img2.data;
    for (let i=0; i<d.length; i+=4) {
        let r = d[i];
        let g = d[i+1];
        let b = d[i+2];

        v1 = r < 75 ? r / (50 - r) : r * (255 - r);
        v2 = g > 75 ? g / (50 - g) : g * (255 - g);
        v3 = b > 75 ? b / (50 - b) : b * (255 - b);

        d[i] = v1;
        d[i+1] = v2;
        d[i+2] = v3;
    }
    console.log(img2.data)
    c.putImageData(img2, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: You can't really derive a proper normal map from a lit "glossy" image, I don't think. If you don't need the alpha channel of the color map, you could put a height map in that channel and use it to derive the normals.

Comment: Ok I will try and see what I can do with that. Thank you for your quick answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say what Three.js can or can't do because all I really know of it is that it makes integrating 3d assets with canvases a breeze.

Aside from that, I wrote a pure javascript function that serves the purpose of generating normal maps from color maps quite effectively. Keep in mind, however, that this is a quick port to js of a function I wrote for C# winforms about 4 years ago, one that loops through all the pixels of a given image to extrapolate the data required for the conversion. It's slow. Seriously, painfully slow and it is so because getting nice, crisp, accurate normal maps from recursive algorithms is painfully slow.

But it does exactly what you want it to do; generate a very nice, clean, precise normal map from a given color map and it's simple enough to understand its functionality.

I've set this up as a [live demo](https://codepen.io/BJS3D/pen/YzjXZgV?editors=1010) so you can see it / feel it in action.

There is, of course, a much faster solution involving making a single call for pixel data, iterating over its corresponding 1d array, saving calculated data back to that array then plopping the entire array, itself, down on the output canvas all at once but that involves some interesting virtual multi-dimensional trickery for Sobel but, for the sake of providing a clear, understandable example that works, I'm going with old-school nested recursion so you can see Sobel in action and how pixels are manipulated to arrive at normalization.

I did not implement any fancy asynchronous updates so you'll only know this is processing because, once initiated, the hand cursor used for the button won't return to the default arrow until map generation is complete.

I've also included 4 variations of your original image to play with, all in code with 3 of the 4 commented out. The app starts at 256x256 as the time it takes to generate a normal map from that with recursion is reasonable. Their sizes range from 128 to the original 1024, though I highly advise not engaging the full scale variant as your browser may whine about how long the operation takes.

As with the C# variant, you can implement a means by which client can control the intensity of the resulting normal calculations by adjusting the brightness parameters. Beyond the C# variant, this definitely can be a basis for generating normal maps to visualize in real-time as applied to geometry with Three.js. And by "real-time", I mean however long it takes to generate an x-scale map with nested recursion because the actual application of a completed map to geometry occurs in milliseconds.

Here's a screenshot of the results after processing the 256x256:

[image]

To accompany the live demo, here's the code:

normalize.htm

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Normalizer</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
</head>
<body onload="startup()">
    <canvas id="input" class="canvas"></canvas>
    <canvas id="output" class="canvas"></canvas>
    <div class="progress">
        <input type="button" class="button" onclick="totallyNormal()" value="Normalize!" />
        <span id="progress">Ready to rock and / or roll on your command!</span>
    </div>
    <script src="js/normalize.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

normalize.css

```
  html {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS";
    background: linear-gradient(330deg, rgb(150, 150, 150), rgb(200, 200, 200));
    background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .canvas {
    outline: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.25);
  }
  .progress {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
  }
  .progress span {
    width: calc(100% - 160px);
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
    text-align: center;
  }
  input[type="button"] {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline;
  }
```

normalize.js

```
// Javascript Normal Map Generator
// Copyright © Brian "BJS3D" Spencer 2022
// Incorporating W3C proposed algorithm to
// calculate pixel brightness in conjunction
// with the Sobel Operator.

var input, output, ctx_i, ctx_o, w, h;

function startup() {
    var img;

    input = document.getElementById("input");
    ctx_i = input.getContext("2d");
    ctx_i.clearRect(0, 0,input.width, input.height);

    img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    //img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/a4N2Aj4.jpg"; //128x128 - Tiny but fast.
    img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/wFe4EG7.jpg"; //256x256 - Takes about a minute.
    //img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/bm4pXrn.jpg"; //512x512 - May take 5 or 10 minutes.
    //img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/aUIdxHH.jpg"; //original - Don't do it! It'll take hours.
    img.onload = function () {
        w = img.width - 1;
        h = img.height - 1;
        input.width = w + 1;
        input.height = h + 1;
        ctx_i.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        output = document.getElementById("output");
        ctx_o = output.getContext("2d");
        output.width = w + 1;
        output.height = h + 1;
    };
}

function totallyNormal() {
    var pixel, x_vector, y_vector;

    for (var y = 0; y < w + 1; y += 1) {
      for (var x = 0; x < h + 1; x += 1) {
        var data = [0, 0, 0, 0, x > 0, x < w, y > 1, y < h, x - 1, x + 1, x, x, y, y, y - 1, y + 1];
        for (var z = 0; z < 4; z +=1) {
          if (data[z + 4]) {
            pixel = ctx_i.getImageData(data[z + 8], data[z + 12], 1, 1);
            data[z] = ((0.299 * (pixel.data[0] / 100)) + (0.587 * (pixel.data[1] / 100)) + (0.114 * (pixel.data[2] / 100)) / 3);
          } else {
            pixel = ctx_i.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
            data[z] = ((0.299 * (pixel.data[0] / 100)) + (0.587 * (pixel.data[1] / 100)) + (0.114 * (pixel.data[2] / 100)) / 3);
          }
        }
        x_vector = parseFloat((Math.abs(data[0] - data[1]) + 1) * 0.5) * 255;
        y_vector = parseFloat((Math.abs(data[2] - data[3]) + 1) * 0.5) * 255;
        ctx_o.fillStyle = "rgba(" + x_vector + "," + y_vector + ",255,255)";
        ctx_o.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
      }
    }
  document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = "Normal map generation complete.";
}
```

Comment: Hi ! Merry Christmas and thank you for your reply. You went to great lengths to provide me with a very functional answer and I thank you very much. I will pass this in my project. Thanks again !

Comment: Merry Christmas, indeed and thank you for the thanks... and for the opportunity to revisit an older project. The example provided turned out to be a springboard for achieving what I implied could be achieved with it by implementing modern techniques in conjunction with the getImageData 1d array. The older C# code I used relied in part on a very C#-specific inherent function that had to be mimicked in js. In this example, perhaps, the function to get pixel brightness is not correct, thus the output is flawed. I'll leave it up as-is because it grants opportunities to achieve milestones in js. :)